# tabulator number editor max and min not working

Tags: numbers, tabulator

i tried to put max and min for number editor ,but it is not working as expected not validation 
my code below

```
 {  , title: "Grade", field: "grade", validator: "required", editor: "number", editorParams: { min: 10, max: 120, step: 1, }     },
```

but it allowed all numbers with no validation ??

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You only have a ***max*** and ***min*** set on the number editor, all this will do is stop you incrementing or decrementing out of the range, it still allows input of any other number, just like a normal number input would do.

You need to use the ***max*** and ***min*** validators for this, at the moment you are only using the ***required*** validator

so your validator property should look like this:

```
validator:["required", "min:10", "max:120"]
```

If you want to your max validator to have a variable maximum then you would need to use a custom validator function for this, in the example below you could change the maxValue variable to look up from a global variable thus allowing you to change it whenever you like:

```
//custom validator 
var variableMax= function(cell, value, parameters){
    var maxValue = 10;

    return value <= maxValue;
}

//assign validator in column definition:
validator:["required", "min:10", {type:variableMax, parameters:{}}]
```

Comment: the issue here i need to make the max dynamic ,something like this validator:["requred", "min:10", "max:MaxDegree"] but with validator it did not work , s oi thought about usign the editor , is there is a way to make the numbers for min and max dynamic in runtime ???

Comment: i have update the example to include using a custom validator function which should do what you need

Comment: it is working fine but in some pages it simply hangs the page and user cannot change the value if the value if more than the max ,is this some thing new ??